# How to set the figure number corresponding to its section and start from 1 in each section

Tags: floats

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{section}-\arabic{figure}}
```

I used this commend, and I get the figure number like this: 1-1,1-2.....2-9.....5-54, but I want to set the figure number to the type that corresponding to its section number and start from 1 at each section, like this, section1: 1-1,1-2,1-3,etc; section2: 2-1,2-2,etc; section3: 3-1,3-2,etc

Comment: Add to the preamble `\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}`

Comment: @JosephYANG, try to ad `\counterwithin{figure}{section}` before your `\renewcommand ...`.